# Отсортировать массив обьектов по значениях свойств соответственно до другого массива

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

К примеру, есть массив

```
 ['Маша','Паша','Даша']
```

и массив обьектов

```
[{id :1, name : 'Даша'},{id :2, name : 'Маша'},{id :3, name : 'Паша'}].
```

Тоесть, в каждом обьекте массива есть свойство name с значением, которое 100% есть в обычном массиве строк.

Нужно отсортировать обьекты в массиве по свойстве name так, что бы они были в таком же порядке, как и имена в обычном массиве строк, вот так должно на выходе быть:

```
 [{id :2, name : 'Маша'}, {id :3, name : 'Паша'}, {id :1, name : 'Даша'}]
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Каждому имени назначить вес. К примеру: Маша - 0, Паша - 1, Даша - 2.
2. Отсортировать по этому признаку.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
'use strict';

const names = ['Маша', 'Паша', 'Даша'];
const indexes = {};
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'Даша'}, {id: 2, name: 'Маша'}, {id: 3, name: 'Паша'}];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    indexes[names[i]] = i;
}

data.sort((a, b) => indexes[a.name] - indexes[b.name]);
```

Теперь в массиве `data` будет:

```
[ { id: 2, name: 'Маша' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Паша' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Даша' } ]
```

Comment: для свертки можно reduce использовать: `indexes = names.reduce((acc,el,i)=>(acc[el]=i, acc),{})`